# What is the equivalent of getAttribute with a parameter in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I have a **Laravel 7** project, that I'm converting to **Laravel 9**. I have a Model called Product with an `accessor` called `getAttribute` **( in my Laravel 7 project ) :**

```
class Product extends from Model
{
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
       return $key;
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent of `getAttribute` with the `$key` in `Laravel 9` please.  I saw the documentation but they give only an example by a column Name like `FirstName`. which is not my case because `getAttribute` is not a column

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one i would be concerned with the implementation, since you are discarding a lot of Laravel logic by overwriting that.

With that said, nothing has changed and it should work the same. I think you are mixing up Eloquent Getters, and this functionality that is a general logic to get properties off a model, as you can see in github in goes through a lot of boilerplate logic for the model property handling.

[GetAttribute implementation](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/6542d0d56f225582a7aa266ea4a0626bdc6bf73f/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L419)